# Redux-saga store converts custom class to plain object

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-saga

I'm trying to store a custom call `User` to the store using my reducer. The problem is, the reducer converts the custom class into a plain object by replacing the Class's properties to the plain object's properties. This means any class methods cannot be called when I get that class from the store.

My User class has a method `getGroup` which cannot be called after retrieving the user from the store.

So an example would be:

```
class User {
   constructor(data){
       this.data = data;
       this.id = data.id;
   }

   getGroup() {
       return this.data.group;
   }
}
```

Will convert to:

```
{
    data: {
        id: 1, 
        group: "Some group"
    },
    id: 1
}
```

I am using `connect` from the `react-redux` library to map the store state to React props.

Any idea how I can either:

- Convert to the correct `User` class when redux saga gets a property from it's store (like a modifying getter)
- Allow the reducer to store my `User` Class

Comment: Are you sure your reducer does that? How do you know that plain object is stored in store and not class instance?

Answer (score 1):

[You shouldn't ever put non-serializable values in the Redux store in the first place](https://redux.js.org/style-guide/style-guide#do-not-put-non-serializable-values-in-state-or-actions):

> **Avoid putting non-serializable values such as Promises, Symbols, Maps/Sets, functions, or class instances into the Redux store state or dispatched actions**. This ensures that capabilities such as debugging via the Redux DevTools will work as expected. It also ensures that the UI will update as expected.

Comment: I saw that a long way back and couldn't find it again. I think I'll need to rely on `react-redux` to transform the state data.